# Is it possible to determine the alignment of the paragraph?

Tags: macros

I have this short code that uses the `\aftergroup command` to inject a `\centering` before inserting a figure and then tries and restore the paragraph settings after the image is typeset.

[image]

I am trying to modify the code so that it can detect the environment that was in before the macro was expanded, i.e if the previous settings were justified then after the image is typeset the environment is restored. How do I do this?

Minimal shown below:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx,lipsum}

\def\agraphic{{\begin{minipage}{3cm}\par \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{./graphics/amato}\end{minipage}\par}}
\def\testafter{{ \gdef\aword{\centering}\aftergroup\aword\aftergroup \agraphic\aftergroup\flushleft }}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\testafter
\lipsum[2]
\agraphic
\lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

Comment: What about `@currenvir`?

Comment: Also, you might want to test the values of `\leftskip` and `\rightskip`.

Comment: Isn't it sufficient to say `\par{\centering\includegraphics[...]{...}\par}`?

Comment: You right I am not sure if @currenvir would do, values could be set from the class definitions or from inline code.

Comment: @egreg This is an extract from some long code, I need to escape outside the enclosing groups.

Comment: I'm with mbork: look at the values of `\leftskip` and `\rightskip`.

Comment: Gents thanks,I didn't think of `\leftskip` and `rightskip`, this would do it. Can one of you please post a short answer so that we can close the question?

Comment: @egreg: I don't think you saw that comment from Yiannis. Do you have time to turn your comment into an answer with a code snippet?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's possible to avoid cumbersome code by simply saying

```
\par{\centering\includegraphics[...]{...}\par}
```

that will restore the previous settings, but center the picture.